# PHP money_format padded number grouping

Tags: php, formatting, numbers

Basically, I'm trying to output a bunch of numbers in a nicely aligned column formatted to look like so:

```
$##,###.##
$##,###.##
```

With the following code

```
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_US.utf8');
money_format('%=0(#5.2n',$sum)
```

it works EXCEPT when $sum is less than 1000. For example, with

```
$sum=1550.00;
```

(as expected) the above code outputs

```
$01,550.00
```

However, with

```
$sum=167.00;
```

the above snippet outputs

```
$000167.00
```

which, obviously, is not what I need. According to the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/de/function.money-format.php)

> Grouping separators will not be applied to fill characters, even if the fill character is a digit.

So, this is the expected behaviour of the function. Doesn't seem to make sense, but that's how it works.

Any suggestions on how to get proper formatting for padded numbers would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: The function makes completely sense if you take into account that the usual fill character is a space. I would not recommend using zeros, also would recommend not to use commas or dots as grouping separators - they are easily mistaken in the other half of the world as decimal separator. One dot or comma per number - every human will take this as the decimal separator.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, Sven. However, this format is a business requirement, I have no say in how it has to look when output. It's an internal-facing part of the application that will not be exposed to those that can mistake commas for dots and vice versa. Also, I see what you're saying about the function making sense when it's approached that way. Nonetheless, I still need a more consistent appearing behaviour, hence, this post.

Answer (score 0):

You could build your own formatting function. [localeconv()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.localeconv.php) will give you data like separators and where the currency symbol should sit. This is one I used, which fit my needs:

```
function my_number_format($amount) {
    // Get separators
    $l = localeconv();

    $str = number_format($amount, 2, $l['decimal_point'], $l['thousands_sep']);

    // manual padding
    while (strlen(preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $str)) < 10) {
        $init = preg_replace('/[^0-9].*/', '', $str); // initial all-digit sequence
        $str = '0' . (strlen($init) == 3 ? $l['thousands_sep'] : '') . $str; 
    }

    return $amount;
}
```